# UserControl accessing DependencyProperty via RelativeSource Self

Tags: wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties, relativesource

I have been having a problem using `RelativeSource` Self in a UserControl. I have contructed two UserControls that I thought would be identical in operation, but one works and the other doesn't. The User Controls themselves consist of just a label whose content I want to set to the `DependencyProperty` Title of the control. When I set the `DataContext` of the UserControl to `RelativeSource` Self, and bind the Label to `Path=Title` everything works fine. If however I bind the Label to `RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType{x:Type UserControl}}, Path=Title` then it fails with a TargetInvocationException.

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong.

This is XAML of the UserControl that works:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControlBinding.Controls.MyLabelControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
      <Label Content="{Binding Path=Title}"></Label>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This is XAML of the code that fails

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControlBinding.Controls.MyLabelControl2"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UserControlBinding.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
      <Label Content="{Binding ReleativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MyLabelControl2}}, Path=Title}"></Label>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the code for your Title property isn't causing a problem (can't tell since it's not listed) everything else looks ok except for the spelling: `ReleativeSource` -> `RelativeSource`